# 2 select filters on Array Values in object

Tags: javascript, angular

I have the below data object:

```
goods = [
    { name: 'Canon', title: 'Canon EOS 5D Mark III Body', tags: ['tag1','tag2','tag3']},
    { name: 'Nikon', title: 'Nikon D3100', tags: ['tag1','tag4','tag5']},
    { name: 'Sony', title: 'Sony CX700', tags: ['tag2','tag3','tag6']},
    { name: 'Fujifilm', title: 'Fujifilm XT20',tags: ['tag1','tag4','tag5']},       
  { name: 'Sony', title: 'Sony CX500', tags: ['tag3','tag4','tag5']},
  { name: 'Nikon', title: 'Nikon D750', tags: ['tag1','tag5','tag6']},
];
```

And a html page with 2 select boxes.

```
<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTag1" (change)="valueSelected1()">
 <option  *ngFor="let item of tagName">{{ item }}</option>
</select>

<select [(ngModel)]="selectedTag2" (change)="valueSelected2()">
 <option  *ngFor="let item of tagName">{{ item }}</option>
</select>

<div *ngFor="let item of goods">
 <app-goods [goodsData]="item"></app-goods>
</div>
```

In my ts file I would like to filter the tags array for selectedTag1, selectedTag2 or Both. i am not sure how to filter the array (do I need to loop through it?) AND I do not know how to combine the 2 filters (do I need combineLatest from RXJS?). I have the below so far

```
  ngOnInit() {
   this.tagName = this.dropdownService.brandName;
   this.goods = this.goodsService.goods;
  };

  public valueSelected1() {
   this.goods = this.goodsService.goods.filter(item => item.tags[0] === this.selectedTag1);
   console.log(this.selectedTag1);
  }
  public valueSelected2() {
   this.goods = this.goodsService.goods.filter(item => item.tags[0] === this.selectedTag1);
   console.log(this.selectedTag2);
  }
```

I think I need to loop through the array here `item.tags[0]` but not sure of the best way to do it and then do a combineLatest.. Maybe not? I have created a [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/2filtersonarrayvalues)

Comment: Changed stackBlitz link as it was wrong.

Comment: *do I need combineLatest from RXJS*...no, you aren't doing anything with *streams*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in one of many number of ways:

1. With a getter

```js
get goodsFiltered(): any[] {
   return this.goods?.filter(({ tags }) => tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag1) !== -1 && tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag2) !== -1) ?? [];
}
```

2. With a [custom pipe](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-pipes-angular/) *(the best way imho)*

```js
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'filteredGoods' })
export class FilteredGoodsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(goods: any[], { tag1, tag2 }): any[] {
    return goods.filter(({ tags }) => tags.indexOf(tag1) !== -1 && tags.indexOf(tag2) !== -1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of goods | filteredGoods: { tag1: selectedTag1, tag2: selectedTag2 }">
 <app-goods [goodsData]="item"></app-goods>
</div>
```

3. Directly in your `change` event callbacks:

```js
  public valueSelected1() {
   this.goods = this.goods.filter(({ tags }) => tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag1) !== -1 && tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag2) !== -1);
  }
  public valueSelected2() {
   this.goods = this.goods.filter(({ tags }) => tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag1) !== -1 && tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag2) !== -1);
  }
```

Hope this helps :)

Edit: I can't tell what types things have, but if `this.goodsService.goods` is an `Observable`, you should pipe the [filter operator](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/filtering/filter):

```js
ngOnInit() {
   this.tagName = this.dropdownService.brandName;
   this.goods = this.goodsService.goods.pipe(
      filter(({ tags }) => tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag1) !== -1 && tags.indexOf(this.selectedTag2) !== -1)
   );
  }
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for all your efforts with this, you have covered everything I could need. Top Answer!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method to check whether array contains `some` values:

```
public valueSelected1() {
    this.goods = this.goodsService.goods.filter(item => 
        item.tags.some(s => s == this.selectedTag1));
    console.log(this.selectedTag1);
}

public valueSelected2() {
    this.goods = this.goodsService.goods.filter(item => 
         item.tags.some( s => s == this.selectedTag1));
    console.log(this.selectedTag2);
}
```

[Please, see a workstackblitz example.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/2filtersonarrayvalues-w3c53m?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use below method instead of **valueSelected1** and **valueSelected2**

```
 public onChangeSelection() {
      this.goods = this.goodsService.goods.filter(item => 
      (this.selectedTag1 && item.tags.includes(this.selectedTag1)) || 
       (this.selectedTag1 && item.tags.includes(this.selectedTag1)));

       console.log(this.selectedTag1);
 }
```

I used the **includes** syntax due to check the **selectedTag** exist in the array and which you checking the first index of the array, I think it's wrong